# how to send HTTP request through java reflection

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reflection, spring-security

i have a method which is developed on spring. The following is my method:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#request, 'CREATE_REQUISITION')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/trade/createrequisition")
    public @ResponseBody
    void createRequisition(@RequestBody CreateRequisitionRO[] request,
            @RequestHeader("validateOnly") boolean validateOnly) {
        logger.debug("Starting createRequisition()...");
        for (int i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
            CreateRequisitionRO requisitionRequest = request[i];

            // FIXME this has to be removed/moved
            requisitionRequest.setFundManager(requisitionRequest.getUserId());
            // FIXME might have to search using param level as well
            SystemDefault sysDefault = dbFuncs.references.systemDefault
                    .findByCompanyAndDivisionAndPortfolio(
                            userContext.getCompany(),
                            userContext.getDivision(),
                            requisitionRequest.getPortfolio());
            requisitionRequest.setCustodianN(sysDefault.getCustodianN());

            gateKeeper.route(requisitionRequest);
        }
    }
```

I would like to call this method through java reflection and the get the response. and the compare the response.

the tomcat is up the user is logged in to the system. while the tomcat is up i have to use the reflection to call the method.

how to do this in java reflection?

Please help and is it possible if possible please suggest me with some inputs if it is not possible support me with the possibilities which will help me to resolve the issue.

EDIT :

this is what i tried but it is not working :

```
Class cls;
        CreateRequisitionRO[] request = new CreateRequisitionRO[10];
        try {
            //load the HexgenWebAPI at runtime
            cls = Class.forName("com.hexgen.api.facade.HexgenWebAPI");
            Object obj = cls.newInstance();

            Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("createRequisition", parames,booleanVal);
            method.invoke(obj, request,true);


        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("status of reflection : "+ex.getCause());
        }
```

Best Regards
Anto

Comment: Can you give an example what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ok, but _what_ are you trying to do? Why do you need to call it with reflection?

Comment: i was trying to have testNG to have unit testing for this method but due to the architecture of the project testNG is not possible to test the method of the class. so we have decided to have reflection to test  whether the method works fine,for this reason only the tomcat is up and user also logged in to the system when i use reflection

Comment: BTW: Your method is annotated with @ResponseBody, but returns void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response to the comments, you're trying to test your Spring MVC controller. I don't see any reason you should have to resolve to reflection to do that. Unit tests are best written and run outside the web container. If you want to do integration testing, check out [Spring-MVC-Test](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework), or use a browser testing framework like [WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) or [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the input, i will check on these and mark your answer if it suits the need. Very kind of you. thanks a lot :)